# Macro - To create one [.csv] file from/using multiple workbooks, kept in a folder, containing multiple worksheets in same other they appear

Tags: excel, vba

I have more than one Excel Workbooks containing multiple worksheets in each of them.

I would like to have a macro which help me to create (combine the information from) all the worksheets into one pipe [|] delimited [.csv] file.

These sheets should be combined/appended into the [.csv] file, in the same order these worksbooks appear in a folder and in the order sheets appear in these workbooks.

The macro should ask for a delimiter/separator specific to me and the input and output path based on my selection.

It would be great if the output [.csv] file is names as "foldername" + "Output.csv"

Thank you,

Best Regards - AJ

Comment: What have you already tried, and what problems did you face? You'll find people here are very happy to help people who are trying to solve problems themselves, but less happy to just "send teh codez".

Comment: Dear Vicky,
Thank you for the response and appreciate the level of encouragement.
But I am absolutely not near to the knowledge of writing VBAs but can only write small queries in excel.
Your help would be the first step towards the class room.

Best Regards - AJ

Comment: AJ, Excel has a beautiful "Macro Recorder". (Tools->Macro->Record up to Excel 2003, Developer->Record Macro in 2007 onwards). That allows you to do the things with UI and look at the code, analyse it and learn from it. In you case you can actually try creating the CSV from one workbook, and later improve it to merge multiple ones. Try it first and come back to this forum if you face any issues there. Do a internet search for any error messages before posting here.

Comment: Thank you for the solution will try the way you have instructed.

Answer (score 0):

here are some way s to save a file as a csv file.

```
    filedir = "C:\etc"
    BookNm = "TheNameOfMyNewCSVFile"

    Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
    With NewBook
        .SaveAs filename:=filedir & Booknm, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    End With

' or '

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filedir & BookNm, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

You should edit your question to tell us what your specific problem is.